# Skype SDK entry point to sign in a user error: NoFQDN

Tags: javascript, jquery, skype, lync-2013, skype4py

I'am trying to sign into Skype via the use of its SDK but I keep hitting the following error, "Error: NoFQDN". After searching this on the net I can't find any possible solution or even find out what the error means. Can anyone shed any light on this or point me towards any useful sources? It would be much appreciated, thanks.

This is my javascript that I'm using to try and log into Skype with.

```
  /**
 * This script demonstrates how to sign the user in and how to sign it out.
 */
$j(function () {
    'use strict';    // create an instance of the Application object;
    // note, that different instances of Application may
    // represent different users
    var Application
    var client;
    Skype.initialize({
        apiKey: 'SWX-BUILD-SDK',
    }, function (api) {
        Application = api.application;
        client = new Application();
    }, function (err) {
        alert('some error occurred: ' + err);
    });

    // when the user clicks on the "Sign In" button    
    $j('#signin').click(function () {
    // start signing in
    client.signInManager.signIn({
        username: $j('#username').text(),
        password: $j('#password').text()
    }).then(
        //onSuccess callback
        function () {
            // when the sign in operation succeeds display the user name
            alert('Signed in as ' + client.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.displayName());
        }, 
        //onFailure callback
        function (error) {
            // if something goes wrong in either of the steps above,
            // display the error message
            alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
        });
    });

    // when the user clicks on the "Sign Out" button
    $j('#signout').click(function () {
    // start signing out
    client.signInManager.signOut()
        .then(
            //onSuccess callback
            function () {
                // and report the success
                alert('Signed out');
            }, 
        //onFailure callback
        function (error) {
            // or a failure
            alert(error || 'Cannot sign in');
        });
    });

    // whenever state changes, display its value    
    client.signInManager.state.changed(function (state) {
        $j('#application_state').text(state);
    });
    });
```

Can anyone see a problem with this?

Comment: Skype is having some issues today, according to [the status page](http://heartbeat.skype.com/2015/09/skype_presence_issues.html). It may be related to your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be the issue as I experienced this last Friday as well unless Skype had issues then as well...

Comment: I have the same issue in my test approach. Did you solve this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

After digging into it: the error message you are getting is pointing out that the sign in parameters (user, password) are "null"/undefined.

Setting values other than "null"/undefined will get the login started. Note that looking at the Javascript code, it is actually a hardcoded check.